# React-Native: How to create a package of my app

Tags: react-native, npm

I need to work on my react-native app from any computer, not only mine.
For the moment, if I need to use another computer to work on my app, I need to install all modules and it can be a large time consuming operation.

I'm wondering if it is possible to create a package of my react-native app, just like any npm package which I add all dependencies and config files (Manifest.xml, Podfile, etc.).

I don't want to push all my project folder on my git repo, too much files...

Is there any good pratice on that subject? How do you manage this situation on your projects?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, git clone is the "like npm" you are describing. On the other computer, you just run git clone, then npm install, then build and run. That's it. Can't be simpler than that, can it?

Comment: As I said, I don't want to use a git solution. For each app I will have a 500 Mb repo just for 1Mb of my own code.

Comment: git also has submodule https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules. If you want to track them but manage them separately, git submodule is an easy solution.

Comment: thank you @cltsang I will take a look to this solution